# defining the value of a field in the view before validating a form

Tags: django, forms

I have a form with a field "status" that will be set by the view depending on the value of some fields of my form

is it possible to do that BEFORE form.is_valid() (otherwise the form won't be valid)?

the only way I can think of doing that is allowing the "status" field to be blank, but that doesn't seem good design

defining a clean() method that set those fields is a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the status field isn't intended be set by the user filling out the form, it probably shouldn't be in the form at all.

If that value is later used in creating/updating a model instance or something, then it would be better to just include the value determined by your view in the form's save method, like `form.save(status=my_status)` (if it's a `ModelForm`) or when you're instantiating your model, otherwise.

If the user does enter the status, then you can just have a custom `clean()` method that ensures it is an acceptable value.

Comment: I want the field to be editable (for instance, in the admin) and not allowed to be blank (even in the admin)... so the form.save(status=my_status) seems a good solution, except it won't work because I should run form.is_valid() before and it will fails. Am I missing something?

Comment: @LuisFernando, it seem like there maybe some confusion between the model and the form here?  You can have a required field in your model that is not included in your form--you'll just have to be sure to set it before saving the model instance (for example, if you use the save option I talked about).  If you're using a ModelForm and don't want to include that field, you can easily exclude it in your ModelForm definition: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form

Answer (score 0):

Then you should init form with this status value and then hide field.

```
class StatusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        super(StatusForm, self).__init__(*arg, **kwargs)
        # set needed value here and hide field
```

Comment: I believe that the OP wants to use the values submitted in the form to determine the status, so setting it in the `init` method won't work, unless he uses the raw POST data (which would generally be a bad plan).